# Why do I get an error when trying to move the mouse？

Tags: ios, swift, macos, cocoa

I want to control the position of the mouse by adding the offset value to the current position. But I have a problem getting the y of the current position. Why?
This is my code：

```
  func moveTouch(offsetPosition: CGPoint) {
    let cursortPosition = NSEvent.mouseLocation
    let resultPosition = CGPoint(x: cursortPosition.x + offsetPosition.x, y: cursortPosition.y + offsetPosition.y)
    CGDisplayMoveCursorToPoint(1, resultPosition)
    let source = CGEventSource.init(stateID: .hidSystemState)
    let eventDown = CGEvent(mouseEventSource: source, mouseType: .mouseMoved, mouseCursorPosition: resultPosition , mouseButton: .left)
    eventDown?.post(tap: .cghidEventTap)
    print("===> cursort:\(cursortPosition)  result:\(resultPosition)  position:\(offsetPosition)")
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

ok, I know! because Because the position obtained by NSEvent.mouseLocation is based on the lower left corner。 And setting the position of CGWarpMouseCursorPosition is based on the lower left corner